# Intuition behind eigen values in Optimization Problems

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

The question may seem very simple, I am not able to understand the intuition behind the solution of following problem

min $A\vec{v}$  where $A$ is some matrix

The solution is the eigen vector associated with minimum eigen value of $A^TA$, I know in general what eigen vectors and eigen values are but I can't find the relation of them in this problem?

Regards 
Ahsan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $ \min A\vec{v}$ is not well-defined as $A\vec{v}$ is a vector. Usually, one is interested in computing

$$ \min_{||\vec{v}|| = 1} ||A\vec{v}|| = \sqrt{\min_{||\vec{v}|| = 1} ||A\vec{v}||^2} = \sqrt{\min_{||\vec{v}|| = 1} (A\vec{v})^T A\vec{v}} = \sqrt{\min_{||\vec{v}|| = 1} \vec{v}^T (A^T A) \vec{v}}. $$

The matrix $A^TA$ is symmetric and non-negative and thus orthogonally diagonalizable with non-negative eigenvalues. By writing $\vec{v}$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors of $A^TA$, you can check that the minimum will be attained when $\vec{v}$ is a unit-length eigenvector associated with the minimum eigenvalue of $A^TA$.